# ImageJ, Java: How can I set Pixels red which are sourounded by red Pixels (avoid holes)

Tags: java, imagej

I have the following problem:

I have written a plugin for ImageJ, which sets specific pixels (the blue ones = cells) to the color red.

Result after setting the blue pixels red

[image: Result]

**Now** I also want to set also all the pixels, which are inside a marked area, to red.

So **I don't want to have any holes**.

Example for a hole:

[image: Example for hole]

I searched the web for hours, but I didn't find anything. I hope somebody knows how I should deal with this issue.

Comment: Why don't you just use _Analyze Particles_ with the _Fill holes_ option? Questions like this are better suited for the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

Comment: No I have to code it, I should not use existing plugins... (It's for school..)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is because the value of blue pixels varies. A better way would be to detect edges and then use flood fill algorithm to fill in the regions inside the boundary.

Found one sample code here http://imagej.net/Level_Sets with github source https://github.com/fiji/level_sets/.

Comment: I know that the alue of blue pixels varies.. but I just want to fill this red holes. And I have to code it beacuse it is for school and we should not use other plugins